# Multiline block showing as one line PHP

Tags: php

I'm just running some example PHP code verbatim, but it's outputting as a single line in my browser. I'm expecting to see new multiple lines.

```
<?php
$author = "Alfred E Newman";

echo <<<_END
This is a Headline

This is the first line.
This is the second.
- Written by $author.
_END;
?>
```

Comment: Sure, that is what is expected. What you call "multi line" defines a multi line string inside php. The browser expects HTML. The browser does not know anything about php. It sees plain text, not HTML markup and displays it as text. You may want to take a look at the `<pre>` html tag, or you want to learn how to output HTML by means of php.

Comment: Browsers collapse whitespace to a single space. You'll need to include `<br>` tags or output the text within `<pre>` tags.

Comment: I see. Was mistakenly assuming that the example intended to preserve the new lines in the output. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your browser by default assumes that any output is HTML and when displaying HTML, newline characters are treated like spaces. You'd either need to output HTML with BR or P tags to force newlines **or** you can send a content-type header to tell the browser that the output you are sending is plain text.

```
<?php
$author = "Alfred E Newman";

// tell the browser that your output is plain text
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo <<<_END
This is a Headline

This is the first line.
This is the second.
- Written by $author.
_END;
?>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I always forget to mention the possibility of changing the content-type when people ask about this. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$author = "Alfred E Newman";

$str = "This is a Headline

This is the first line.
This is the second.
- Written by $author.
";

echo nl2br($str);
?>
```

will give you what you need;